# React Native evaluate an expression in this.state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Have been trying to get something to work like this. Super new to React Native so I am not sure if it is even allowed.

```
class SearchPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      day: '',
      time: ''
   };

  _renderContent(section, i, isActive) {
    var name = section.identifier;
    // for example the value of name is 'day'
    // how would I be able to access this.state.day here? 
  }

  // other code including render function
}
```

I have tried `this.state.{name}` and other things too but they don't work. Can someone help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

state will be a javascript object so you can evaluate something like this:

```
const variableName = "day"

this.state[variableName] // this is equivilant to this.state.day
```

Comment: AHHHH totally didn't realize i could have just done that. thanks so much! it worked (: